# sizeof operator in c

Tags: c

please can anybody help me to implement `sizeof()` operator in c..

i know the usage .. but i was not able to implement it.

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you getting stuck? Do you get any errors? Are you writing a compiler?

Comment: no .. actually am going to implement behaviour of the sizeof operator

Comment: for example if sizeof('t') den output is 1

Comment: please be more specific. The only context in which "implement sizeof" makes sense is if you were writing a compiler. It cannot be implemented as a library function (otherwise it probably would have been...).

Comment: your example doesn't really make sense. Do you want to do something like: `printf("%d\n", sizeof('t'));`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't implement `sizeof` in C; it's a basic operator (you can't implement `+` either).

You could write a macro that has a limited subset of `sizeof`'s behavior, by doing something along the lines of:

```
#define thisIsAHorribleHackDontDoThis(a) \
    ((size_t)((intptr_t)(&a + 1) - (intptr_t)&a))
```

but that only works if `a` is an lvalue (and it's horrible to behold).  `sizeof` is not so limited, and that's why you should use it instead of reinventing a wheel that isn't actually round.

Comment: Or `#define mysizeof(type) ((size_t)((char *)((type *)0+1) - (char *)0))`

Comment: @R: one should mix your two approaches to be "maximum portable". `intptr_t` is not necessarily defined but `(char*)(void*)&a` is. On the other hand, if I remember correctly, doing arithmetic on null pointers is UB.

Answer (score 10):

You cannot implement `sizeof()` as a library function, it is a compiler intrinsic. Are you writing a compiler?

Comment: for example if sizeof('t') den output is 1

Comment: @RAVI J V:  It is unlikely that the result of `sizeof('t')` is `1` on your computer because a character constant is of type `int` in C, not `char` (yes, `int` _could_ be one byte in size if a byte has at least 16 bits; it's just unlikely that you have a system where this is the case).

Comment: @James Are you sure about that? I'm pretty sure that 't' will be of type char which is guaranteed to be 8 bytes...

Comment: @Paul: in c character constants have a type of `int`. in c++ they have a type of `char`.

Comment: @Paul: Yes.  In C, character constants have type `int`, whereas in C++ they have type `char`.  See http://david.tribble.com/text/cdiffs.htm#C99-char-literal .

Comment: @Paul: "An integer character constant has type int." (§6.4.4.4)

Comment: @Evan Interesting. So you're saying 'char c = 'a';' ends up being a cast from int to char, but the compiler can know that it'll never overflow so there's no warning?

Comment: @Paul: not a cast. An implicit conversion.

Comment: Well *I* definitely learned something here - thanks guys!

Answer (score -2):

Below is the implementation of ***sizeof*** operator

```
#define SZOF(x) (size_t)(((x*)(0))+1)
```

Comment: that only works for some *type* x; sizeof also works on variable names. Also , this is pretty much the same as R.'s comment  to Stephen Canon's answer, above.